# MS Dynamics Great Plains Authentication - No Connection Could Be Made

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-gp

I am trying to pull a list of vendors from my local instance of Great Plains.

When I visit

```
http://localhost:48620/DynamicsGPWebServices/DynamicsGPService.asmx
```

I am asked to login. I enter my windows credentials, then I see endpoint not found.

I know that the web service exists.

I know that my windows credentials are correct because they are the admin account.

I have the sample company installed.

Here is my code:

```cs
   DynamicsGP g = new DynamicsGP();
        g.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");

        // Create an instance of the web service want to do this
        //asynchronously.  

        // Be sure the default credentials are used
        //g.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

        // Create a context with which to call the web service
        Context context = new Context();

        // Specify which company to use (sample company)
        var companyKey = new CompanyKey();
        companyKey.Id = (-1);

        // Set up the context object
        context.OrganizationKey = (OrganizationKey)companyKey;
        context.CultureName = "en-US";

        //error occurs after this line
        VendorSummary[] vs = g.GetVendorList(new VendorCriteria(), context);
```

I receive this error:

> {System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> > System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively > refused it 127.0.0.1:48260
>   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
>   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, > Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Int32 > timeout, Exception& exception)
>     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>     at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
>     at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
>     at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
>     at PMInvoices.DynamicsGPService.DynamicsGP.GetVendorList(VendorCriteria criteria, Context Context) in >c:\Users\joe_a84\Downloads\DeveloperToolkitSampleApps\PMInvoices\PMInvoices\PMInvoices\Web References\DynamicsGPService\Reference.cs:line 4069

Answer (score 0):

I see the URL is this:

```
http://machinename:48620/DynamicsGPWebServices
```

where machinename is localhost.